# Allow application specific access in iptables using guid

Tags: iptables

I would like to get Skype working with `iptables` and don't want to allow a huge range of ports thus I thought a solution might be

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner skypeGrp -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -m owner --gid-owner skypeGrp -j ACCEPT
```

where in advance I had created a group called `skypeGrp` and then put the skype application into it:

```
sudo addgroup skypeGrp
sudo usermod some_username -G skypeGrp
sudo chgrp skypeGrp /usr/bin/skype
```

Shouldn't this work?

EDIT:

I think another key insight here to make the method I originally outlined in my question work, is to realise that it `active group` that `iptables` takes notice of. Thus my user doesn't just have to belong to the `skypeGrp`, this also must be his `active group` at the time of running `Skype` (see [here](http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/iptables) for more).

Answer (score 3):

No because the rule will check against the groups of the user, and not the group owner of the file.

But if you setgid the skype executable, the group owner of the file will also be part of the groups of the user.

```
chmod g+s /usr/bin/skype
```

Then your `iptables` rules should work... if Skype works and does not drop privileges.

Comment: My user that will be running Skype does not have `sudo` privileges, so cannot `chmod`, how else can I achieve this for that user? (I edited my answer to put the user in the `skypeGrp` as well, although this didn't seem to fix anything)

Comment: OK, let's say my user is called `userChild` so I did `chown userChild /usr/bin/skype` followed by `chmod g+s /usr/bin/skype` when logged in as `userChild`. So now `ls -l` says `-rwxr-xr-x 1 userChild skypeGrp 28356768 Nov  1 01:19 /usr/bin/skype`

Comment: the `chmod g+s` must obviously be made by root, this is a privileged operation. your ls -l shows clearly your file is not setgid.

Comment: `ls -l` now gives `-rwxr-sr-x 1 root skypeGrp 8429 Oct 30  2011 /usr/bin/skype` and `id userChild` gives `uid=1000(userChild) gid=1000(userChild),1006(skype),1000(userChild)`. This still does not seem to work however.

Comment: Indeed even doing `chmod u+s` as root to setuid as root for skype giving `ls -l` `-rwsr-sr-x 1 root skypeGrp 8429 Oct 30  2011 /usr/bin/skype` doesn't work. Even though I have the rule `iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner root -j ACCEPT` allowing all OUTPUT from root.

Comment: doesn't `chmod g+s` set the application to run with YOUR group id while the file is executing, so doing the `chmod g+s` as root would mean it ran with the `root` groups. Whereas really I wanted it to run by inheriting the `userChild` groups which include skypeGrp; hence why I originally changed ownership to `userChild` and let him do the `chmod g+s`. Either way I don't think it is working- I added `root` to the `skypeGrp` as well for good measure.

Comment: Maybe it's just that skype can't be abused this way.

Comment: Maybe...if that is the case, any other ideas with how I can get skype and iptables to work well together (other than just opening all the ingoing/outgoing high ports)

Comment: Well, i would think of netns or other kind of hacks like this, but that's way more complicated.